# Javascript String array with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JS Array of strings:

```
for(var i =0; i<db.length; i++)
    console.log(db[i]);
```

And the output:

```
dbName:rf,dbStatus:true
dbName:rt,dbStatus:false
```

And I want to loop over with ng-repeat:

```
$scope.DBArray = db;
```

in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "line in DBArray">
      {{line.dbName}} - line.dbStatus
    </li>
</ul>
```

The loop does not work for now. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, still not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is not looping or some binding is missing? Are rt and rf defined? Shouldn't it be {{line.dbStatus}?

Comment: dbName:'rf',dbStatus:true
dbName:'rt',dbStatus:false

dbName value should be string

Comment: I thnik the problem is in the loop, the binding is shown on console.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly braces on the second line.dbStatus
The output of the js array doesn't look like json or an array to me.

```
dbName:rf,dbStatus:true
dbName:rt,dbStatus:false
```

should be more like

```
[{
    dbName:rf,dbStatus:true
 },
 {
    dbName:rt,dbStatus:false
}]
```

That could be on problem, for ng-repeat to not work.

Have a look at the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aNZaF69f6UzmycsEUHKQ)

Answer (score -1):

As it seems DBArray is array of objects with properties dbName and dbStatus

update your html to

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "line in DBArray">
      {{line.dbName}} - {{line.dbStatus}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

hopefully it works.

please send the complete error on colsole if it still doesn't works.

problem was line.dbStatus should be in angular expression `{{**line.dbSatus**}}`

Comment: No that is not the problem.